# Can you approve edits to your own posts?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I haven't had opportunity to test this, but can low-rep users approve other users' edits of their own posts?

Example:

> - User1 (100 rep) writes a Question or Answer.
> - User2 (100 rep) edits User1's post to fix spelling, convert a URL to inline image, and some other cleanup.

Can User1 approve User2's edits, or does User1 have to wait for a higher-rep user to step in?

Comment: I've just been irritated by the fact that i've made a post, and somebody made an edit and it has asked me to approve of it. I read through the edit, I approve it and it tells me I don't have the rep to approve it. This is the second time now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The person who originally posted the post can *always* vote to approve or reject a suggested edit to that post. Note that on Stack Overflow, two votes must occur for action to take place, as opposed to other Stack Exchange sites, where one vote is binding.

See: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/)

Comment: Aw, and I created two accounts just to test it out.  Oh well, I shall have to save them for another day.

Comment: Had no clue you could approve edits to your own post (although when I think about it now, it makes sense). Thanks for this information.

Answer (score 3):

I have 31 reputation and I don't get any notifications or anything to approve edits made on my own posts.

Comment: @MSameer - Nobody except *extremely* high-rep users (or is it still diamond-mods only) gets alerts for pending edits.  You'd have to actually go check your post to see if there are any.

Comment: yep, anyone over 5000+ has a suggested edits page under review which has a queue of all edits (Just pass 5K myself =D)

Comment: @Iszi  alerts for pending edit, like this you mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263633/why-ask-me-to-approve-an-edit-to-my-own-post-and-when-i-dont-have-the-rep-to    note my rep here is low like 200 and I still got an edit notification

Comment: @barlop Also note that this thread is *extremely* old and many UI changes have since been made - which very well could include edit notifications for low-rep users, at least on their own posts.