# Can a question's OP approve suggested edits on their question?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

On **Stack Overflow** (not Meta) I've noticed that sometimes my suggested edits are approved by the question's OP *only*. That is, no one else reviews the suggestion.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1216969)
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1216976)

Strangely, these questions [Can you approve edits to your own posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84517/can-you-approve-edits-to-your-own-posts) and [It takes two to tango?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/151586#151586) say it takes **two** or more votes.

Can the OP's vote alone approve an edit now (contrary to what the questions above say), or is this simply the system's way of dealing with edit clashes?

Comment: it's not a duplicate, it sites that question as a source, that question says it takes two, but this addresses that they can be approved with only one

Comment: @dea - It's in there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> **Who can vote on a suggested edit?**
>
> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.

Their vote is binding.

Comment: But that's a **vote** to approve or reject, not a approval or rejection it self. And where does it say they are binding?

Comment: @DeadChex: Now it does. :)

Comment: But where on StackOverflow? ;)

Comment: There are *tons* of things that aren't mentioned on Stack Overflow itself.