# Is this a valid edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, review, suggested-edits

I was just on the Suggested Edits tab, and noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1599366) edit. It is obviously not valid, and I rejected it. However, it was approved by two people (one a new reviewer, the other somewhat new). I then went to the question and took it back out. Was I right to do this, or have our tag-in-title rules changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's was a useless edit. It should not have been approved. I'm surprised it was.

Tags already appear in the `<title>` of the question, and should not be added to  the actual question title. The correct action would be **Reject**, reason: **Custom -> "Don't put tags in titles"** or **"too minor"** if you don't feel like typing.

---

The edit merely appended `[python]` to the existing title and changed nothing else:

> Comment: added python to title to help people searching through the titles
>
> #### conditional keypress via command line [python]

I can't comment on the motive of the edit, as there *may* be something to it (although you really should just use tags to search in a language, not titles). If you really honestly feel you *must* use a tag in a title, do it in a natural way. For a (bad, unnecessary) example:

> #### Conditional keypress via command line in Python

...still, usually you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Indeed; it would more likely be a valid edit to *remove* a tag from a title!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: One of the reviewers is apparently a ColdFusion dev, so his judgement might be a little scrambled.

Comment: Also note that one of the reviewers is the author of the original post, hence why the edit was approved.

Comment: @Wesley the other reviewer reviewed it first (hover over the times to see the *exact* time in a tooltip)

Comment: @Emmett Just saw that, it was like .5 seconds difference between the reviews. Originally I read it wrong, that the author approved it first.

Answer (score 4):

It puzzled me why there were only 2 approve votes, and ironically - it got approved from the OP... So, I guess the OP is relatively new, or thought it was a good edit, and the other reviewer is just new... But I agree, the edit shouldn't have been approved, but then the OP's approval is final!

Comment: Really? That was the OP (the new one or the newish one?)

Comment: @Linuxios `jml` approved the edit to his own post... Although with 500 rep, that seems a bit odd... but yeah...

Comment: OP's vote on suggested edits is final: [Can a question's OP approve suggested edits on the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159781) /cc @Linuxios

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Alright. Makes sense.

Comment: @JonClements: It does. Why he would be in the queue, for the *first* time, for an edit on his question... I'm gonna do some looking.

Comment: @linuxios You get notified when an edit has been made to your post... They may have clicked onto that

Comment: @Linuxios: You get notifications for edits (suggested or completed) on your post; there's also an indicator on the "edit" link below the post itself.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, JonClements: Forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a little silly to me - I wouldn't have approved it, personally. But then again, unfortunately many people seem to just approve things without really giving much thought.