# Why ask me to approve an edit to my own post *and* when I don't have the rep to?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

1. I make a post.
2. Somebody suggests an edit.
3. I get notified that an edit has been made, and I get asked to approve it.
4. Then it tells me that I don't have the rep to (approve?).
5. …so it goes in the queue.

Firstly I should be able to approve an edit to my own post without needing high rep.

And secondly, if I don't have the rep to approve an edit to my own post then the system shouldn't pester me with telling me that an edit has been made and giving me the approve button to click which after clicking next, doesn't approve it.

For anybody that doubts that I received a message, even being less than the 2k rep requirement…

1. A screenshot that I got the notification about an edit made to my own post

   [image: inbox — edit suggested]
2. A screenshot of the review page. Notice my rep isn't high though I still got that page.

   [image: Review Suggested Edits]
3. So it shouldn't have asked me to approve it in the first place. And when I click Next I get this message:

   [image: You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.]

**Added**

I see it let me review it. So it shouldn't say I "need 2K rep to review suggested edits".. that message made me unsure whether i'd just managed to review my post or not.  If anything, it should say you need 2K rep to review suggested edits of other peoples' posts. Or better, return to the question - as suggested in an answer

Comment: You can approve an edit to your own post at any rep. The second screenshot shows that you did.

Comment: @Mat And did you not see the third screenshot that says "You need 2K rep to review suggested edits", which kind of contradicts where you say "You can approve an edit to your own post at any rep."  And if you say i'm not reviewing it i'm editing it.. Then how am I not reviewing it when it says in text there in the second screenshot "Review" And it's not quite clear to me how I would be looking at somebody's edit , in a screen like that, without reviewing it

Comment: The second screenshot shows that you reviewed and approved the suggestion. I assume you clicked the "Next" button after that? If it's, then it will take you to "Suggested Edits Review Queue" (for *all* suggestions, not only to your posts) that needs 2k. Probably confusing for new users.

Comment: The "Next" button shouldn't be available for those who have no future in the review queue.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils you mean(to be more clear), the next button shouldn't be available when there is nothing in the queue for them to review.

Comment: And the text that says "You need at least 2K reputation to review suggested edits" should say "to review suggested edits of other peoples' posts" and it should only appear if there was some kind of attempt to edit other peoples' posts - which there wasn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Firstly I should be able to approve an edit to my own post without needing high rep.

Guess what, you are.

The third screenshot simply refers to how under normal circumstances you'd need 2000 rep to access the review queue *generally*. Because an edit was made to your post, **you were only allowed to review the edit there**. Even your second screenshot shows that you approved it.

Reviewing edits for any post requires 2000 rep, but **you're able to review only edits to your posts while you have under 2000.**

Comment: Put another way, the reason the queue has that "need at least 2k" message is because the OP is not allowed to ***continue*** reviewing, as would otherwise be the case after reviewing a suggestion.

Comment: It wasn't clear what Next was doing, considering that I hadn't clicked anything to review a queue of edits of various peoples' posts. It was one review of ,my post that I got notified of. The next looked to me like a superfluous button.. I see though that clicking that notification sent me to the public reviews queue thing.

Answer (score 10):

As said already, you can, and you have, approved the suggested edit.

The thing that confuses you is the dialog you get next, and so it does to me. I have always wondered why it doesn't take me where I can from or the post I just have reviewed, instead of the next item in the queue. Of course, for 2K+ users this could be a reminder to do some reviews, but still I think it is most useful to go to the post instead.

<strike>I will see if there is a feature request to do this already. If not, I will create one.</strike>

Created a feature request here: [Return to post after reviewing a suggested edit on an own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263657/245360).

Comment: I don't think there is such a request, but might be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I've thought this when I was in that scenario. It would make more sense to be redirected to the relevant area we *were* viewing/working on prior to the edit.

Comment: @James sounds reasonable. Added it.